# How do I uninstall a PHP module?

Tags: php

I bumped into this bit of instructions while installing an addon for a PHP framework:

```
Make sure you don't have the PHP module installed. This is a Debian/Ubuntu example:

sudo apt-get purge php5-geoip
```

I am working on Windows PC with a Virtual Machine running Laravel Homsetead. I am using Git Bash command window. When I enter the above command I get:

```
bash: sudo: command not found
```

If I remember correctly, `sudo` is an Apple-related command so I tried dropping it like this:

```
apt-get purge php5-geoip
```

but I get

```
bash: apt-get: command not found
```

What command do I need to use to `purge php5-geoip`?

**EDIT:** echo $PATH gives out:

```
$ echo $PATH
/c/Users/Arthur/bin:/mingw64/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/mingw64/bin:/usr/
bin:/c/Users/Arthur/bin:/c/ProgramData/Oracle/Java/javapath:/c/Windows/system32:
/c/Windows:/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/
c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/OpenCL SDK/2.0/bin/x86:/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/
OpenCL SDK/2.0/bin/x64:/c/Program Files (x86)/NVIDIA Corporation/PhysX/Common:/c
/Program Files/MATLAB/MATLAB Production Server/R2015a/runtime/win64:/c/Program F
iles/MATLAB/MATLAB Production Server/R2015a/bin:/c/Program Files/MATLAB/MATLAB P
roduction Server/R2015a/polyspace/bin:/c/Program Files (x86)/Skype/Phone:/c/PHP:
/c/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin:/c/Users/Arthur/AppData/Roaming/Composer/vendor
/bin:/c/HashiCorp/Vagrant/bin:/c/Program Files/nodejs:/c/Users/Arthur/AppData/Ro
aming/npm:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl
```

Comment: `sudo` is not apple-related, rather it's common across most modern Unix-like environments. Your Homestead VM should have it. This sounds like a problem with your `$PATH` environment variable in homestead, not finding the commands rather than them not being present.  do `echo $PATH`. The output _should_ include `/usr/bin` where those 2 commands  reside.

Comment: Oh wait, are you typing the apt-get commands into _Windows_ via git-bash? They need to be executed against the Ubuntu virtual machine.  Windows will not translate them down into the VM.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I ran `echo $PATH`, but there are several instances of `/usr/bin`. I am not sure what to do about it. I pasted the output of `echo $PATH` to the question. How do I execute a command against Virtual Machine? Should I do it in the Git Bash window where I have it running? It doesn't work from the `homestead` folder

Comment: Which operating system is the virtual machine running? Just remove the `extension=geoip.so` from the php.ini and delete the module itself..

Comment: @DanFromGermany I feel like a supernoob. I am almost sure it is Ubuntu. There is no `extension` with any `geo` prefix in `php.ini` so I guess it is not installed.. But I checked `C:/PHP/php.ini` file. I am not sure if this is the one that my Virtual Machine uses

Comment: When you view your laravel application at localhost:8888 (or whatever it is), you are are seeing a port (8888) translated from Windows (localhost) into the running Ubuntu homestead VM. It is inside the VM that PHP must be configured.  To connect to it [according to the Homestead docs](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/homestead#daily-usage), you would use `homestead ssh` from within Windows/git-bash. Then once that SSH connection is made into the VM, you would run `sudo apt-get....`    But it is unlikely that you already have the geoip extension installed. It is not a common default.